# syntax explanation for pattern matching a list in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was reading [this](http://blog.tmorris.net/the-power-of-type-classes-with-scala-implicit-defs/) blog post and i was not able to understand a part of the code.

```
object O {
  def maximum(x: List[Int]): Int = x match {
  case Nil => error("maximum undefined for empty list")
  case x :: y :: ys => maximum((if(x > y) x else y) :: ys)
  case x :: _ => x
 }
}
```

Please explain the code `maximum((if(x > y) x else y) :: ys)`

How the `if` condition can be a part of the method `maximum` ?
I understand that if condition is not exactly a parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Scala, `if` is an expression, not a statement.

Try this in the REPL:

```
scala> val x=1; val y=0
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 0

scala> val test=if(x > y) x else y
test: Int = 1
```

`if` evaluates to 1 and 1 is assigned to test. In Java `if` could be expressed with the conditional operator `(x > y) ? x : y`

Now, you have a function called `maximum` that takes a `List[Int]` as a parameter. 
`maximum((if(x > y) x else y) :: ys)` calls maximum (recursively) with a list obtained prepending one between `x` and `y` (depending on what the if evaluates to) to `ys`.